# No se puede obtener token JWT de cookie en navegador Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, cookies

Tengo una api desarrollada en ASP.NET Core que genera un token JWT y lo envía a una cookie para la autenticación de usuarios, sin embargo al ejecutar un método para recuperar el nombre del usuario en cuyo método trato de recuperar el token de la cookie no me es posible en el navegador Chrome, cabe mencionar que si lo puedo recuperar en Mozilla y en Postman pero no en Chrome y no me tira ningún error. Buscando información sobre este error me parece que el problema esta en la configuración de SameSite, hice la prueba con SameSiteMode.Lax ya que permite el envío de cookies entre sitios (mi front esta en local en Angular) pero no funciono. ¿Alguien podría orientarme por favor?

**Método Login que envía el token a la cookie:**

```
 [HttpPost("login")]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginDTO dto)
    {
        var user = _repository.GetByEmail(dto.Email);

        if (user == null) return BadRequest(new { message = "Credenciales invalidas" });

       
        var jwt = _jwtService.Generate(user.Id);

        Response.Cookies.Append("jwt", jwt, new CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
           

        });

        return Ok(new
        {
            message="success"
        });
    }
```

**Método que genera el token**

```
public string Generate(int id)
    {
        var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secureKey));
        var credenciales = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var header = new JwtHeader(credenciales);

        var payload = new JwtPayload(id.ToString(), null, null, null, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));
        var securityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(securityToken);
    }
```

**Método que debe recuperar el token de la cookie (solo en Chrome no lo obtiene y le asigna null)**

```
[HttpGet("user")]
    public IActionResult User()
    {
        try
        {
            var jwt = Request.Cookies["jwt"];

            if(jwt != null)
            {
                var token = _jwtService.Verify(jwt);

                int userid = int.Parse(token.Issuer);

                var user = _repository.GetById(userid);

                return Ok(user);
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

    }
```

Comment: El problema no es el back, es el front, y la configuracion de la cookie. fijate que usualmente, el navegador tira algun error en la consola sobre este tema...